# value comparator or something else?

Tags: bash, shell

I am fairly new to shell scripting and I ran into a line in a shell script I was looking at that I do not understand:

```
echo 107 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

I am wondering, is the '>' operator comparing a value in export with 107 or is it placing the value 107 into export?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46289472

Comment: The `>` is simply a redirction of `stdout` from `echo 107` into the file `/sys/class/gpio/export`. You can try a simply case yourself. Open an xterm and just type `echo "hello" > somefile.txt`. Now `cat somefile.txt` to see it contains `hello`. (just remember `>` replaces the file content while `>>` appends to the file)

Comment: Check out [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo+107+>+%2Fsys%2Fclass%2Fgpio%2Fexport)

Comment: This isn't specific to shell scripting. You do it all the time when you want to save the output of a command into a file, don't you?

Comment: Alright, thanks David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your following instruction:

```
echo 107 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

Can be seen like that:

- the `echo` instruction is used to print the *107* string value
- the > is redirecting this output to */sys/class/gpio/export* which is the target file path

Like proposed in comments, you can have some information in [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo%20107%20%3E%20%2Fsys%2Fclass%2Fgpio%2Fexport).

To learn more, you should read the [redirect](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output) part of the GNU/Bash Manual.
What can be important here:

- notion of `standard output` and `error output`
- redirecting output (`>`) VS appending redirection output (`>>`)